# How to capture the error to redis in node.js

Tags: node.js, redis

In my application im using redis database with node.js.Now i want to build error capture module .How can i capture error in redis.Using Airbrake(https://github.com/felixge/node-airbrake) we can capture error but how can i do that on my own using redis in node.js.

Comment: Did you consider using [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis)? It has error handling built in.

Comment: @migg yes im using node_redis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the code for `node-airbrake`, you'll notice this:

```
Airbrake.prototype.handleExceptions = function() {
  var self = this;
  process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    self._onError(err, true)
  });
};
```

So, you could implement your own `uncaughtException` handler (although some say that doing so is bad form, but that's another discussion) and store your errors in Redis.